# Understand interface TX & RX counters for bridged mode interfaces

Tags: linux, linux-networking, linux-kernel

I have a Linux gateway running interfaces in transparent bridged mode. Here eth0=WAN, eth1=LAN. Ideally, I believe eth0 RX = eth1 TX bytes and same way eth1 RX = eth0 TX bytes. But it seems huge gap in those interfaces. How br0 interface counters affect here ?

```
root@###########:/# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ##########  
          inet addr:#########  Bcast:##########  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47262194 errors:0 dropped:4614 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41869458 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:13170460498 (12.2 GiB)  TX bytes:70134118715 (65.3 GiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ############ 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:148465632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38848017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:79098297056 (73.6 GiB)  TX bytes:61360499863 (57.1 GiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr #############  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9301779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10364291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1098222281 (1.0 GiB)  TX bytes:12775528535 (11.8 GiB)
```